# What story this is? Boy named Arthur steals bananas with his helibackpack

Tags: story-identification

I don't really remember much, since it was when I was in the 2nd grade, but I read a story in which there was a boy named Arthur. I don't remember the plot nor many of the other characters, but there was a scene where Arthur steals a batch of bananas with his helibackpack? The whole setting was sort of fantasy-ish, and also the illustrations were a bit steampunk but also primitive. Also, the antagonist of the story wanted to murder cheese wheels (the cheese were alive. I know, this was a strange book), so that he could make a cheese fondue. Anyone recognize this book?

Comment: This does not seem to be about an sf or fantasy work.

Comment: I thought it was more on the fantasy side

Comment: This reminds me of a PC game I played about 10 years ago... You sure it was a book?

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't a dream?

Comment: @Beta haha yeah it does sound a bit trippy what with the *helibackpack banana thief* and *sentient cheese*

Comment: Ya it was a real book with some illustrations. But I think it should be a sort of kid's book since I read it in the second grade :)

Comment: Although this is the older question/answer, I found https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/189893/looking-for-surrealist-ridicule-book-about-a-boy-with-a-wingsuit to be more comprehensive in question and answer, so I marked this as a duplicate to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the book!!!
Its a fantasy book called *Here Be Monsters: The Ratbridge Chronicles Part 1.* It took a bit of digging but the plot is slightly different from what I remembered. Here's the link to the wikipedia article: [Here Be Monsters! - Wikipedia the Free Encyclopedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_Be_Monsters!)

Comment: Could you add some information about the book? It may be helpful for future travellers